# Calabash: Increase wait timeout for predefined step

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

```
Then I wait to see "Choose a drink:#0"                           
# calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:154
  execution expired (Calabash::Cucumber::WaitHelpers::WaitError)
```

While using predefined steps, it works fine in local. However it fails in CI. There are no network calls made. It's just a transition to a new screen.

Any ideas on how to increase the wait timeout for the predefined steps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to write your own step.

If you look at the [step](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/calabash-cucumber/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb) you can see that if you set `WAIT_TIMEOUT` you can increase the wait time.

```
$ WAIT_TIMEOUT=120 bundle exec cucumber
```

I think you should write your own step.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me try and will let you know if it works. Regarding writing own steps, I know that's the right way to go. I'm using pre-defined steps for a different experiment.